# Did d3 v5.8 release break transition of styles when using numbers?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have d3 v5 code in my application that transitions the height of a div using a number. This no longer works since today's release of v5.8:

```
d3.select("div").transition().style("height", 100)
```

If I change it to...

```
d3.select("div").transition().style("height", "100px")
```

it works again. The original value before transition is ...style("height", 0) which shows as an html inline-style height of "0px".

Did this change happen in today's release? Was this change intended? Is it considered bad practice to use numbers like this in d3? Thanks.

EDIT
I've added an example below. The height for div1 doesn't transition because it's using a number instead of a string with px units.

```js
d3.select("#div1").transition().style("height", 100)

d3.select("#div2").transition().style("height", "100px")
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="background-color:purple;height=10px;width=100px"></div>
<div id="div2" style="background-color:red;height=10px;width=100px"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT2: I've added a running example in v5.7 below where you can see that both transitions work. I had oversimplified my original example. I had to add the css in this example to replicate what I'm seeing in my actual application
. It seems to now be related to the inline-flex style and I'm not sure why.

```js
d3.select("#div1").transition().style("height", 100)

d3.select("#div2").transition().style("height", "100px")
```

```css
#parent-div {
  width:100px;
  display:inline-flex;
}
.sub-div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-div" style="position:absolute;top:10px;width:100px">
  <div id="div1" class="sub-div" style="background-color:purple;height=0px"></div>
  <div id="div2" class="sub-div" style="background-color:red;height=10px">    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just edited my answer asking for a demo: the specific example you gave won't work neither on v5.7 nor v5.8. Can you please post a very simple running example of your code working on v5.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the new D3 v5.8 does have a new interpolator. If you look at the [releases notes](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases) for D3 v5.8, released today (29/Jan/2019 at the time of writing), you'll see:

> Fix interpolation in transition.style and transition.attr in certain non-string cases.

The problem can be easily demonstrated here, using v5.8, where we try to interpolate `"20px"` to `100` (that is, string to number):

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const rect = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", "20px")
  .attr("height", "20px")
rect.transition()
  .duration(10)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .on("end", function() {
    console.log(rect.attr("width"))
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

As you can see, you'll get a `NaN`!

Note that it won't happen in v5.7:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");
const rect = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", "20px")
  .attr("height", "20px")
rect.transition()
  .duration(10)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .on("end", function() {
    console.log(rect.attr("width"))
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Anyway, answering your question:

> Is it considered bad practice to use numbers like this in d3?

Yes, it is (I have to confess I do that sometimes), but this is not D3 related: if you have `"20px"` (a string) as the initial state you should have `"100px"` (a string) as the final state, not `100` (a number). This makes the interpolation more clear and less error-prone.

This is not your case, though: you have numbers in both initial and final state. What's happening in your case is that, even if you use a number (like `0`) as the initial state, the getter will get `"0px"`, as a string. Finally, it's worth mentioning that your specific example doesn't work neither on v5.7 nor v5.8, so I'd suggest that you post a very simple working example using v5.7 in your question.

**EDIT**

As requested, you edited your question with working examples, thanks for that.

Regarding your example #1, it won't work with D3 v5.7 as well, that was my point above (*"your specific example doesn't work neither on v5.7 nor v5.8"*). Have a look, no purple div (both heights starting at `0px`):

```js
d3.select("#div1").transition().style("height", 100)
d3.select("#div2").transition().style("height", "100px")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" style="background-color:purple;height:0px;width:100px"></div>
<div id="div2" style="background-color:red;height:0px;width:100px"></div>
```

I said that it won't work on D3 v5.7 as well because I was under the impression, after you write `style("height", 0)`, that you had previously set the style using D3.

But here in your first example we find a problem: you're using `=` instead of `:` in the inline style (that seems to explain the weird behaviour, keep reading).

Regarding your second example, it doesn't work if you use the correct syntax for the inline style, even with D3 v5.7, have a look:

```js
d3.select("#div1").transition().style("height", 100)
d3.select("#div2").transition().style("height", "100px")
```

```css
#parent-div {
  width:100px;
  display:inline-flex;
}
.sub-div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-div" style="position:absolute;top:10px;width:100px">
  <div id="div1" class="sub-div" style="background-color:purple;height:0px"></div>
  <div id="div2" class="sub-div" style="background-color:red;height:10px"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

So, what's happening here is just an unfortunate combination of `inline-flex` with an incorrect inline style (that is, not correctly setting the height to 0px), which made the purple div expanding to the parent. We can see that in the demo below, where I'm transitioning **only the red div**:

```js
d3.select("#div2").transition().style("height", "100px")
```

```css
#parent-div {
  width:100px;
  display:inline-flex;
}
.sub-div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-div" style="position:absolute;top:10px;width:100px">
  <div id="div1" class="sub-div" style="background-color:purple;height=0px"></div>
  <div id="div2" class="sub-div" style="background-color:red;height=10px">    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Gerardo, I've added some running examples to demonstrate what I was seeing. It was a bit more complicated than I had originally posted--I guess that's why it's good to include running examples in the first place. I'm still not sure what is happening. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @moki well, the mystery is probably just an incorrect inline style: it has to be `:` instead of `=`.